# inequality in commutative diagram using tikz

Tags: tikz-arrows

I am trying to draw a commutative diagram using tikz-cd, where one of the arrow is an inequality. I know equality arrows are \ar[equal], does anyone know how to draw inequality arrows? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE and happy Christmas. Please can you add a picture, a code (.tex), anything to understand your question.

Comment: What is the mathematical meaning of *inequality arrow*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this? (Orientation changed, thanks to @Sigur!)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\tikzset{
inequality/.style={postaction={decorate,decoration={markings,
mark=at position 0.5 with {\draw (1.5pt,4pt) -- (-1.5pt,-4pt);}}}}}
\begin{document}
Equality:
\[
\begin{tikzcd}
X \ar[equal]{r} & Y 
\end{tikzcd}
\]

Inequality:
\[
\begin{tikzcd}
X \ar[equal,inequality]{r} & Y
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I don't know why, but what came first to my mind was something related with `\leq` not with `\neq`... lol :-)

Comment: @Sigur We will find out, I hope. I agree that your interpretation makes at least as much sense as mine, and as you may know [my crystal ball](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qOr3L.png) got stolen, so I had to guess.

Comment: I'm mathematician and so *inequality* to me first means `\leq`... a lot of inequalities in analysis.

Comment: @Sigur I am a marmot, and use Wikipedia *if* it supports my claims. Otherwise I ignore it.;-) Anyway, according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_(mathematics)), either of us could be right. Or someone who would argue that one should use `\geq`.

Comment: Sorry for writing, but maybe you could change orientation of the slanted bar... lol it looks reflected.

Comment: Nice. Now it is more mathematical!

Comment: Thanks so much! This is exactly what I was looking for. Sorry for the confusion.